# Why isn't the string in this block of code being updated?

Tags: javascript

I assume this is a small error that I'm missing somewhere. The var `JSONurl` at the top of the top of the code should be changed by the `changecoin()` function. However when `changecoin()` is called by the webpage, the function executes but the `JSONurl` string doesn't change and stays at its initial value.

```
/*jslint plusplus: true */
//console.log("javascript is working");
"use strict";

var lastPrice;
var initSet = 0;
var JSONurl = "http://coincap.io/page/XRP";

document.getElementById("dropdown-btc").addEventListener("click", function(){
    changeCoin("btc");
});

document.getElementById("dropdown-eth").addEventListener("click", function(){
    changeCoin("eth");
});

document.getElementById("dropdown-xrp").addEventListener("click", function(){
    changeCoin("xrp");
});



$( document ).ready(function () {
    console.log( "ready!" );
    getRippleVals(JSONurl);
    //setInterval(getRippleVals(JSONurl), 5000);

});


function getRippleVals(JSONurl) {
    console.log("");
    var url = JSONurl;
    console.log("JSON URL: " + url);
    console.log("Gloval JSON URL: " + JSONurl);
    $.getJSON(url,
            function (data) {

            //function commands, not relevant

          });
          setTimeout(getRippleVals, 5000, JSONurl);

}



function bFormatter(num) {
    return num > 999999999 ? (num/1000000000).toFixed(2) + 'Bn' : num
}

function changeCoin(coin)
{
  console.log(coin);
  var coin = coin.toUpperCase();
  $("#dropdownMenuButton").html(coin);

  if(coin === "BTC")
  {
    JSONurl = "http://coincap.io/page/BTC";
    $("#pairing-text").html("BTC : USD");
    lastPrice = 0;
    console.log("JSONurl set to: " + "http://coincap.io/page/BTC");
  }
  else if(coin === "ETH")
  {
    JSONurl = "http://coincap.io/page/ETH";
    $("#pairing-text").html("ETH : USD");
    lastPrice = 0;
    console.log("JSONurl set to: " + "http://coincap.io/page/ETH");
  }
  else if(coin === "XRP")
  {
    JSONurl = "http://coincap.io/page/XRP";
    $("#pairing-text").html("XRP : USD");
    lastPrice = 0;
    console.log("JSONurl set to: " + "http://coincap.io/page/XRP");
  }

}
```

Comment: Can you show the corresponding HTML? Is changeCoin only called once? It looks like an event leak where the three listeners are called at each click so your variable always contains XRP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your setTimeout you are calling in `getRippleVals` you keep passing in the initial JSONurl so it will always be what you first set it.

It looks like you tried using setInterval (which is the proper way to repeat the function) and you just needed to use an anonymous function to pass in a parameter (JSONurl) to `getRippleVals`

```js
"use strict";

var lastPrice;
var initSet = 0;
var JSONurl = "http://coincap.io/page/XRP";

document.getElementById("dropdown-btc").addEventListener("click", function() {
  changeCoin("btc");
});

document.getElementById("dropdown-eth").addEventListener("click", function() {
  changeCoin("eth");
});

document.getElementById("dropdown-xrp").addEventListener("click", function() {
  changeCoin("xrp");
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log("ready!");
  getRippleVals(JSONurl);
  //** use setInterval like below
  setInterval(function() {
    getRippleVals(JSONurl)
  }, 5000);

});

function getRippleVals(JSONurl) {
  console.log("");
  var url = JSONurl;
  //console.log("JSON URL: " + url);
  console.log("Global JSON URL: " + JSONurl);
  $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    //function commands, not relevant
  });
  // take out this setTimeout
  //setTimeout(getRippleVals, 5000, JSONurl);

}

function changeCoin(coin) {
  console.log(coin);
  var coin = coin.toUpperCase();
  $("#dropdownMenuButton").html(coin);

  if (coin === "BTC") {
    JSONurl = "http://coincap.io/page/BTC";
    $("#pairing-text").html("BTC : USD");
    lastPrice = 0;
    console.log("JSONurl set to: " + "http://coincap.io/page/BTC");
  } else if (coin === "ETH") {
    JSONurl = "http://coincap.io/page/ETH";
    $("#pairing-text").html("ETH : USD");
    lastPrice = 0;
    console.log("JSONurl set to: " + "http://coincap.io/page/ETH");
  } else if (coin === "XRP") {
    JSONurl = "http://coincap.io/page/XRP";
    $("#pairing-text").html("XRP : USD");
    lastPrice = 0;
    console.log("JSONurl set to: " + "http://coincap.io/page/XRP");
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="dropdown-btc">BTC</button>
<button id="dropdown-eth">ETH</button>
<button id="dropdown-xrp">XRP</button>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you for your advice. I knew there would be some small error that was causing the problem. If I can just ask, why are anonymous functions used in this case?

Comment: using an anonymous function in this case is to allow you to call a function with parameters, the setInterval method wants a function (like `setInterval(getRippleVals, 5000)`) and not `setInterval(getRippleVals(JSONurl), 5000)` which calls the function and passes the return value to setInterval. You can read more here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval